# Change text color on button push WIN32

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I change the text color from an edit box on button push? (Win32/C++).
I know how to change the text font (i.e. to use in `WM_COMMAND`, `SendMessage()` with
`WM_SETFONT`).

On changing text color I think that I need an interaction between`WM_COMMAND`,   `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`, and `SendMessage()` but don't know with what kind of parameter .
Thank you.


I've figured how to do this on single button.
One more question please. If I use the code above for 3 different buttons, it doesn't behave as expected . There is a snippet :

```cpp
case IDC_BUTTON3:
{
    textFlagRed = textFlagRed;
    textFlagBlue = !textFlagBlue;
    textFlagGreen = !textFlagGreen;
    InvalidateRect(textArea2, NULL, TRUE);
    break;
}

case IDC_BUTTON4:
{
    textFlagGreen = textFlagGreen;
    textFlagBlue = !textFlagBlue;
    textFlagRed = !textFlagRed;
    InvalidateRect(textArea2, NULL, TRUE);
    break;
}

case IDC_BUTTON5:
{
    textFlagBlue = textFlagBlue;
    textFlagRed = !textFlagRed;
    textFlagGreen = !textFlagGreen;
    InvalidateRect(textArea2, NULL, TRUE);
    break;
}
```

and  in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`

```cpp
if (textFlagRed && (HWND)lParam == textArea2)
{   
    HBRUSH hbr = (HBRUSH) DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    SetTextColor((HDC) wParam, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    return (BOOL) hbr;
}
else if (textFlagBlue && (HWND)lParam == textArea2)
{   
    HBRUSH hbr = (HBRUSH) DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    SetTextColor((HDC) wParam, RGB(0, 0, 255));
    return (BOOL) hbr;
}
else if (textFlagGreen && (HWND)lParam == textArea2)
{   
    HBRUSH hbr = (HBRUSH) DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    SetTextColor((HDC) wParam, RGB(0, 255, 0));
    return (BOOL) hbr;
} 
break;
```

Always is the blue color.

Comment: I can't really see anything blatantly wong with the logic -- try putting in debug statements and/or breakpoints to see the values of variables and why it is always showing blue?

Comment: That was my mess , variables were not declared as static. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

**a)** a global boolean to indicate if the colour needs to be chaanged (say `bEditRed`)

**b)** on button push: set/toggle `bEditRed` and invalidate the edit box `InvalidateRect(hWndEdit, NULL, TRUE)`

**c)** handle the `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT' message in your dialog proc:

```cpp
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
{   if (bEditRed && (HWND)lParam == hWndEdit)
    {   HBRUSH hbr = (HBRUSH) DefWindowProc(hDlg, iMessage, wParam, lParam);
        SetTextColor((HDC) wParam, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        return (BOOL) hbr;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Actually the text is red from the begining.

Comment: @rhauder_ - indeed. Just create a variable that will serve as a boolean flag. If flag set **and** `if ((HWND)lParam == hWndEdit)` then you run the code. Just set/toggle/clear the flag in your button handler, then invalidate the edit control.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Edward's answer is to use

```
RedrawWindow(windowHandle, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
```

instead of

```
InvalidateRect(windowHandle, NULL, TRUE)
```

The former will immediately redraw your window, while the latter will not redraw it until the main window is available again.